# Change compass image in Map

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mkmapview, compass

Like you can see in the title: I'd like to change the compass image displayed in my MapView.

I'm creating a `MKCompassButtonView` using these lines:

```
let compassBtn = MKCompassButton(mapView:MapView)
compassBtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 25)
compassBtn.compassVisibility = .visible
MapView.addSubview(compassBtn)
```

... but how can I edit the compass image? *(Changing the color / etc. is possible but I'd like to set my own compass image)*

### [image: img]

Using some code like this:

```
compassBtn.image = UIImageView(UIImage(named: "myImage"))
```

.... is still not working `"compassBtn" has no member ".image"`.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The one which you have pointed out is the location icon. Below the location icon is the compass icon

Comment: Yeah you're right but I have not pointed on this image. I've searched for 'map compass ios' and this was the first image popping up :) @Nitish

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit it as it the default MK Compass Button provided by Apple, if you read the docs at : [MK Compass Button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcompassbutton?language=objc) you can check theres no functions or methods to change the image, if you want to change the image just create your own view in that corner with 2 buttons that share the same height inside.